# Presto equivalent of MySQL group_concat

Tags: mysql, presto, group-concat, trino

I'm new to Presto and looking to get the same functionality as the group_concat function in MySQL. Are the following two equivalent? If not, any suggestions for how I can recreate the group_concat functionality in Presto?

MySQL:

```
select 
  a,
  group_concat(b separator ',')
from table
group by a
```

Presto:

```
select 
  a,
  array_join(array_agg(b), ',')
from table
group by a
```

(Found this as a suggested Presto workaround [here](http://qiita.com/toyama0919/items/add6c9b03747394c0038) when searching group_concat functionality.)

Answer (score 55):

Try using this in place of group_concat in Presto ::

```
select 
  a,
  array_join(array_agg(b), ',')
from table
group by a
```

Comment: For those who see an unexpected order in the aggregation, you can use `array_agg(x ORDER BY y)`

Answer (score 30):

Also, if you're looking for unique values only – an equivalent to `group_concat(distinct ... separator ', ')` – try this:

```
array_join(array_distinct(array_agg(...)), ', ')
```

Comment: I've found that (in this particular case of achieving *distinct* `group_concat`) using nested queries for manually taking `DISTINCT` values performs better than the `array_distinct` **UDF**. Not sure that this would be *universally true* though

Comment: You can simplify this to `array_agg(distinct b)` and leave off the `array_distanct()` part

Answer (score 5):

There's no function as of this answer, [though the feature has been requested](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/1976).

The closest equivalent is mentioned in your question.

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT 'hey' AS str1
UNION ALL
SELECT ' there'
)
SELECT array_join(array_agg(str1), ',', '') AS joined
FROM tmp
```