# How convert rows to map in presto?

Tags: sql, presto

Consider SQL statement:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM (
  SELECT key, value, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY length(value) DESC) AS rn
  FROM my_table
)
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

This produces:

```
key value
A   1
A   2
B   10
```

How to make this like:

```
key values
A   [1;2;3;4;5]
B   [10;20;30;40;50]
```

Sql engine is presto. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try  array_join(array_agg(value), ',')? I found a relevant post. Please check out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142356/presto-equivalent-of-mysql-group-concat

Comment: Many thanks for the quickest reply! `map_agg` is the solution! :)

Comment: most welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`map_agg`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#map_agg) is the solution:

```
SELECT key, map_agg(key, value)
FROM (
  SELECT key, value, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY length(value) DESC) AS rn
  FROM my_table
)
WHERE rn <= 5 group by key;
```

Many thanks, @Shantanu Kher for the quickest reply!