# Merge row values based on other column value

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to merge the values of two rows based on the value of another row in a different column. Below is my based table

| Customer ID | Property ID | Bookings per customer | Cancellations per customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 100 | 1 |
| C | 4 | 100 | 1 |
| D | 5 | 20 | 1 |

Here is the SQL query I used

```
select customer_id, property_id, bookings_per_customer, cancellations_per_customer
from table
```

And this is what I want to see. Any ideas the query to get this would be? We use presto SQL

Thanks!

| Customer ID | Property ID | Bookings per customer | Cancellations per customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| C | 3 , 4 | 100 | 1 |
| D | 5 | 20 | 1 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142356/presto-equivalent-of-mysql-group-concat can perhaps help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try:

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(property_id), ',') AS properties,
    bookings_per_customer,
    cancellations_per_customer
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    customer_id,
    bookings_per_customer,
    cancellations_per_customer;
```