# Group multiple rows values into a single row

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to merge multiple row values for same id into a single row value separated by commas

How can do this in Athena?

This is the data:

[image]

This is the expected result:

[image: [After]()]

I appreciate your help and ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Do not post code and data as images. Also please be sure to show your attempt and explanation what is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presto equivalent of MySQL group\_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142356/presto-equivalent-of-mysql-group-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) aggregate function:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, interest) as(
    values (1,  'Math'),
        (1,  'Poetry'),
        (1,  'Art'),
        (2,  'Math'),
        (2,  'Other')
)

-- query
select id, array_agg(interest) interest
from dataset
group by id
```

Output:

| id | interest |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Math, Poetry, Art] |
| 2 | [Math, Other] |

Comment: @GraciaM was glad to help! But be sure to compose a better question next time - see the comment to the question (P.S. you can upvote answers also wink-wink ;).